# Can I make a loading screen

Tags: batch-file, loading, hta

Is it possible to make a loading screen like this one [here](http://t.imgbox.com/acznUTog.jpg), if so, how would I go about making one, would it be possible to make it in batch? Or in HTA (Hyper Text Application).

I have been wondering for a long time.

Thanks

**EDIT**
This question has been resolved, thank you to all who helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6525239/) is exactly what your are looking for It's a code using (batch, VBS and Hta)
there is 5 skins you can use by setting the variable `$model` (1 to 5).

The skins are already included in the code in Binary,

You can run it as it is to test it and then adapt it for your situation.

**EDIT :**

To add Your own skins you have to convert an animated GIF in HEXA. You can use this
[code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6529686/) from HACKOO to do it.
And then you can integrate your own skin :

```
:MODEL6
(echo Set oExec = Ws.Exec^(^"mshta.exe ^" ^& Temp ^& ^"^\Barre.hta^"^)
echo ^'THE HEXA CODE OF YOUR ANIMATED GIF HERE)>>waitbar.vbs
goto:eof
```

And just set the `$model` value to 6 and enjoy

Comment: This is perfect, one problem, how would i add the skins?

Comment: Check the EDIT in the Original Message to integrate your own skins.

Comment: If you have problem to do it pass me the link of your GIF I'll integrate it for you.

Comment: Could you Please explain to me how you added the background music and how you made the splash screen? This is rely cool.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "write=<nul set/p"
%write%=Loading

for /l %%a in (1,1,25) do (
  %write%=.
  ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul
)
echo. Thank you for waiting.
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example showing you how to search for files and backup by extensions with a Splash Screen](http://pastebin.com/LcvYGqUS)

It is a Vbscript to search for files by their extensions and organize them by copying in different folders with names on their extensions chosen from the beginning of the research. and generate search results in a table in HTML, citing information on these files such that their paths, creation date, modification date, size and attributes,and display thumbnails of diffrent types of images in the search, Eg if the search includes image files will be displayed as thumbnails.

Comment: Could you Please explain to me how you added the background music and how you made the splash screen?

Comment: To add background music you can edit this line for example :
tempFile.Writeline "<bgsound src=""http://www.soundjay.com/mechanical/explosion-03.mp3"">"